# How to import properly a jar dependency into a .jar file generated by Ant?

Tags: java, ant, jar, build, executable-jar

I am pretty new in **Ant** and I have the following problem trying to create a **build.xml** file to compile a single class (that contains the **main()** method) command line application.

So this is the code of the **Main** class (at this time it is the only class in the application):

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World !!!");

        System.out.println(args.length);

        if(args.length != 0) {
            String partitaIVA = args[0];
            String nomePDF = args[1];
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement  stmt = null;

        try {
            Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

            TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/GMT+2");
            TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);

            // Step 1: Allocate a database "Connection" object
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1521:eme1", "myUserName", "myPswd");    // Oracle DB driver 

            System.out.println("After obtained connection with DB");

        } catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the behavior of the **main()** method is very simple, at this time only obtain a connection with an **Oracle** database (represented by the **Connection conn** object). Running it into the IDE (I am using **IntelliJ) it works fine (I can see it using the debugger, the **Connection conn** is correctly set).

Now I am working on the following **build.xml** file for the **Ant** compilation:

```
<project name="edi-sta">

    <description>
        EDI-STA
    </description>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/Main.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run">
        <java jar="build/jar/Main.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

After that I have performed in order the **clean**, **compile** and **jar** targets I tried to open the console, access to the **build/jar/** directory that contains the **Main.jar** file and I try to execute it performing the following statement:

```
C:\Projects\edi-sta\build\jar>java -jar Main.jar
Hello World !!!
0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Unknown Source)

C:\Projects\edi-sta\build\jar>
```

But, as you can see, now happens a very strange thing, it seems that can't found the class that contains the Oracle driver (**oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver**) so the **ClassNotFoundException** is thrown.

I think that this happens because if I open (with WinZip) my generated **Main.jar** file it only contains the **Main.class** file and the **META-INF** folder (that contains only the MANIFEST.MF file) but I have not the **ojdbc6.jar** file that contains the Oracle driver that I use.

So my question is: what have I to do to include this **ojdbc6.jar** dependency properly in my generated **Main.jar** file and avoid the **ClassNotFoundException**?

Tnx

Comment: First of all, don't use ANT. But if you absolutely insist, you need to add it to the &lt<jar> task. (Or you specify it on the command line). Dont forget to check the license situation if you include proprietary software.

Answer (score -1):

You can define jar dependencies in the Class-Path attribute of the manifest file of the jar. Read the documentation here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

To achieve that from your ant task, use the Class-Path attribute as below

```
  <jar destfile="build/jar/Main.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="your-jar-file"/> 
                ....
```

Comment: Now I will try. But what have I to put as value? The name of my jar or something like /lib/filename.jar ?

Comment: The manifest should contain the path of the referred-to jar file relative to the jar file that refers to it. So where is filename.jar relative to Main.jar ?